# Calculating a parameter based on values from the previous day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, pandas-loc

I have a DataFrame which is part of a wider script on Python with the following characteristics:

- index `dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=365, freq='D'`
- daily values for different parameters
- a default value for DOY 1
- a pair of values I previously calculated for some specific dates.

To date, the dataframe structure is something like this:

```python
                 col1    col2      col3       col4       Condition   value to calculate
2018-01-01        5.0  0.853232  0.992774   0.65377        0.0       0.65429
2018-01-02        0.4  0.004652  0.992774   0.65377        0.0       NaN
2018-01-03        0.0  0.000000  0.992774   0.65377        0.0       NaN
2018-01-04        0.0  0.000000  0.992774   0.65377        1.0       0.33456
2018-01-05        0.4  0.004652  0.992774   0.65377        0.0       NaN
              ...       ...       ...       ...        ...       ...
```

The 'condition' column was used to attribute values at a specific time in the last column

The missing values in the last column should be calculated using data from columns 1 to 4, using values of the previous DOY from both columns 1 to 4 and from the same column of the value that must me calculated.

Also, in case a value is already present at a specific DOY, the formula should reset to start calculation using the previously added value.

I'm not sure how to put this in a loop to execute the operation, or if there are other alternatives to resolve this part of the code I'm working on.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the problem fully. 
It would be helpful to understand the algorithm needed for the last column computation. 

It seems like you need something like this: 

for index, row in df.iterrows():
      start_row = index - n 
      end_row = inde - m
      other_rows = df.loc[start_row:end_row]
      compute_last_column(row, other_rows)

Comment: @Cr4zyTun4 that's not actually an algorithm, it's just a formula to evaluate soil erosion (in particular, soil roughness). Calculation is trickier since mechanical operations can affect daily values, which are affected by the previous day parameters, so calculation should be something like `value at day x = col1(x-1)*col2(x-1)-col3(x-1)*col4(x-1)`

Comment: Ok cool, did you understand the iterrow() approach or do you need me to sketch some code?

Comment: I'd ask for your help cause I'm not entirely sure I understood how iterrows() works

Comment: maybe calculate it for every day normally and later use `shift()` to move all values one row down to put result in next date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need something like this:
def compute_value(previous_row, row):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
      if index>0:
           previous_row = df.iloc[index-1]
           row['value to calculate'] = previous_row['col1'] * previous_row['col2'] - previous_row['col3'] * previous_row['col4']
```

This is how you iterate but not sure to have fully understood the condition and not sure what you meant with, let me know if I can expand

> Also, in case a value is already present at a specific DOY, the formula should reset to start calculation using the previously added value.

Comment: Glad that was helpful! Have a good work!

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been doing some adjustments to make it work, like converting the DatetimeIndex into a DOY to avoid the 
`TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.  Instead of adding/subtracting 'n', use 'n * obj.freq' `

There's one more thing I'd ask for your (or anyone else's reading) help: the result I'm trying to calculate is based on the values of columns 1 to 4 of the previous day, but also on the value obtained from the previous day of the same result I'm trying to calculate.